# Attempted to load class "Imagick" from the global namespace in symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, imagick

So I'm currently using "Imagick" extension for a symfony project, but I get this error:

**ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "Imagick" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?"**

Strangely, it's working fine in all native php script, but not working in symfony project!

I did some research and I found that I need to enable imagick for CLI also .. but I didn't find any method explain how to make it.

So, I verified Imagick installation by this code snippet:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new imagick("C:/wamp64/www/test/image.jpg");
$image->thumbnailImage(100,0);

echo $image;
```

and I can see the image loaded correctly.

Also, when I run this script from the browser:

```
<?php

if (extension_loaded('imagick')){
    echo 'imagick is installed';
} else {
    echo 'imagick not installed';
}

?>
```

I get :

`imagick is installed`

But when I execute this file from command-line interface, I get :

`imagick not installed`

In the Symfony project I get this error log:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "Imagick" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?"
```

**Symfony function**

```
private function createThumbnail($path, $dest, $width, $height)
    {
        $im = new \Imagick();
        $im->pingImage($path);
        $im->readImage($path);
        $im->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
        $white=new \Imagick();
        $white->newImage($width, $height, "white");
        $white->compositeImage($im, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
        $white->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $white->writeImage($dest);
        $im->destroy();
        $white->destroy();
    }
```

**Environment**

PHP Version => 7.1.9

System => Windows 10

Server => Wamp64

Symfony version => 3.1

Compiler => MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)

Architecture => x64

imagick module version => 3.4.3

ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27

Comment: Please, show the code where you are using Imagick class

Comment: on the command line run `php -i` and somewhere in the first 20 lines (some of which are *very* long, the configure command that is) you should find the location of the `Configuration file` that is being read, also additional files. In those files, you have to enable the imagick extension, which I hope you know how to do (usually removing the `;` in front of the line that says `extension=imagick` or php_imagick or whatever or you might have to add it, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Comment: And "Imagick" is the correct name of the class? In your plain php example, you write "imagick", all lowecase

Comment: @Jakumi Yes, I already did everything you said, so the imagick extention is enabled in wamp, the proof is imagick works in all native php script, I tried to follow this tutorial on how to install and enable the Imagick extension: [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows)

@pabgaran, Yes, It is correct .. As far as I know `$im = new \Imagick();` similar to `use Imagick; $im = new imagick();`

I have deployed this project on SSH server, and it is working fine, but still not working on my windows localhost

Comment: there are too many environments for me: am I getting this correctly... remote (unix) via web: ok, remote (unix) via command line: ok, local (windows) via web: ok, local (windows) via command line: NOPE. ? if so, have you followed the very last advice given on your link regarding "In case of console error" and have you also called from local cli "php -i" and checked for the config file? because as far as I can tell, it's probably neither php nor the server per se, but some configuration that's wrong or file at wrong location or something outside symfony

Comment: Yes sir, when I run my symfony application locally during development by the PHP CLI SAPI with this command : `php bin/console serve:run` => imagick extention didn't work, but the same project works fine on the remote SSH server (Linux), 

the strange is when I use a native php script with imagick on wamp apache server, it's working for me. Someone told me that he suspects I access by embedded symfony server so in that way I access by CLI not Apache, so I need to enable imagick for CLI also, but I don't have any idea about that.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I put the answer for someone who have the same issue:

you should add the following lines

```
;on Windows:
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

```
;on UNIX:
extension = imagick.so
```

to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpx.x.x\php.ini`

not to `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apachex.x.x\bin\php.ini`

because the first php.ini is the file used by PHP CLI, so by the Symfony Local Web Server.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

The **complete ImageMagick/Symfony installation steps** are the following (here for Windows):

1. Download the package from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.5.1/windows
2. Extract from php_imagick-….zip the php_imagick.dll file, and save it to the ext directory of your PHP installation
3. Extract the dependencies
   •   For PHP 5.x/7.x: Extract from ImageMagick-….zip the DLL files located in the bin folder that start with CORE_RL or IM_MOD_RL or FILTER, and save them to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe), or to a directory in your PATH variable:
   •   17 files CORE_RL*.dll
   •   126 files IM_MOD_RL*.dll
   •   1 files FILTER*.dll
   •   For PHP 8.x: Extract from php_imagick-….zip the DLL files that start with CORE_RL or IM_MOD_RL or FILTER, and save them to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe), or to a directory in your PATH variable
4. Add this line to your php.ini file: extension=php_imagick.dll
5. Restart the Apache/NGINX Windows service (if applicable)
6. Check if the install is correct through phpinfo() for which a specific imagick block has been added
7. Don’t forget to add use Imagick; to your php file